# Unrar files spanned across multiple DVDs

Tags: archive

I am just starting to get the hang of Ubuntu, so please bear with me.

I want to extract a RAR file of size 8GB. Now I have backed up the file on 2 DVDs after splitting the files in 40 pieces of 200MB each; first disc has 21 parts and second disc has the rest. When I start extraction, it extracts 21 parts, but after that Archive Manager throws an error

`Cannot find the volume: archivename.part22.rar`

I understand that the problem is Archive Manager is not showing a dialog to find the other files on the next disc. I can counter it by just copying the all parts from the disk in one directory before extracting, but copying 8GB of data every time I want to extract anything is very time consuming, takes a lot of space on my small hard drive, and I have many such archives.

Can anyone point me to some other program that can do the same? I googled but found nothing, nor any other solution. I am using Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Are both discs mounted at the same time?

Comment: My 1st test would be to do this command line, have it run into the error, insert the 2nd disc and then use the partly merged file to merge with the 2nd disc.

Comment: @Rinzwind. No both the disk are physically loaded into tray and one at a time if you meant I am mounting the disk images. Also as I am just starting I don't know the commands that much. I will google it.